# How to create 100 JButtons at once

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

So I am supposed to make a game of Battleship which is 10x10. I was wondering if there was a way to create and instantiate 100 JButtons at once without having to go through and create/instantiate each one manually. Each with a number at the end corresponding to it's position on the board. eg. 00 for col 0 row 0.

Thanks,

Jeff

Comment: By putting it in a loop.

Comment: Yes but each button needs to have a different name. Such as Fireshot00, Fireshot 01 etc..

Comment: How about creating the name in the loop? Also, people are expected to show what they already tried.

Comment: Then no, you can't. You could put them in an array, or some other data structure.

Comment: Aye indeed, I know how to create and instantiate the variables, I was just wondering if there was a shortcut out there then typing out 0-99 on each one, then doing the same for the instantiation part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JButton[][] button = new JButton[10][10];
String str = "fireshot";

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
     for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
     {
        button[i][j] = new JButton(str+i+j);
     }

}
```

Comment: If I had the rep to upvote you I would. Thank you kind sir you have saved me hours of mundane coding.

Answer (score 3):

```
JButton [][] buttons = new JButton[numRows][numCols];
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; ++j) {
        buttons[i][j] = new JButton(String.format("Button %d, %d", i, j));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a `JTable` and specify as cell renderer your own which uses a single JButton.

Answer (score 0):

you have to set GridLayout to set the position of button.